# react change class name on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state like this where I am setting `active` and `class` flag like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {'active': false, 'class': 'album'};
}

handleClick(id) {
  if(this.state.active){
    this.setState({'active': false,'class': 'album'})
  }else{
    this.setState({'active': true,'class': 'active'})
  }
}
```

And I have a list of items with class name from state:

```
<div className={this.state.class} key={data.id} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this.data.id}>
  <p>{data.name}</p>
</div>
```

Here how can I change the class name of particular div?

Comment: You'll have to post more of your code. If the `<div>` is in the render method of the component that you're describing in your first code snippet, then yes, that should work.

Comment: Yes it is in render method.. but all the div in the list are changing .. I want to change the class of the div which I have clicked..

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Below is a fully functional example of what I believe you're trying to do (with a functional snippet).

## Explanation

Based on your question, you seem to be modifying 1 property in `state` for all of your elements. That's why when you click on one, all of them are being changed.

In particular, notice that the state tracks an index of *which* element is active. When `MyClickable` is clicked, it tells the `Container` its index, `Container` updates the `state`, and subsequently the `isActive` property of the appropriate `MyClickable`s.

## Example

```js
class Container extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeIndex: null
  }

  handleClick = (index) => this.setState({ activeIndex: index })

  render() {
    return <div>
      <MyClickable name="a" index={0} isActive={ this.state.activeIndex===0 } onClick={ this.handleClick } />
      <MyClickable name="b" index={1} isActive={ this.state.activeIndex===1 } onClick={ this.handleClick }/>
      <MyClickable name="c" index={2} isActive={ this.state.activeIndex===2 } onClick={ this.handleClick }/>
    </div>
  }
}

class MyClickable extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => this.props.onClick(this.props.index)
  
  render() {
    return <button
      type='button'
      className={
        this.props.isActive ? 'active' : 'album'
      }
      onClick={ this.handleClick }
    >
      <span>{ this.props.name }</span>
    </button>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.album>span:after {
  content: ' (an album)';
}

.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.active>span:after {
  content: ' ACTIVE';
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

## Update: "Loops"

In response to a comment about a "loop" version, I believe the question is about rendering an array of `MyClickable` elements. We won't use a loop, but [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which is typical in React + JSX. The following should give you the same result as above, but it works with an array of elements.

```
// New render method for `Container`
render() {
  const clickables = [
    { name: "a" },
    { name: "b" },
    { name: "c" },
  ]

  return <div>
      { clickables.map(function(clickable, i) {
          return <MyClickable key={ clickable.name }
            name={ clickable.name }
            index={ i }
            isActive={ this.state.activeIndex === i }
            onClick={ this.handleClick }
          />
        } )
      }
  </div>
}
```

Comment: are the onClick assigned on the component construction and in the container the same onClicks?  why do you need 4 onclick methods setting property and state, confused

Comment: @maxwell That can be confusing. `onClick` is a `prop` of `MyClickable`. It is a function that is *passed to* `MyClickable`. Each `MyClickable` is passed the `handleClick` function defined in `Container`. Then the `MyClickable` is responsible for calling this function at the appropriate time and with the appropriate arguments. This is the typical way in which a parent component's state is updated based on what occurs in a child component. In this example, each `MyClickable` will call their `onClick` function with their index, effectively telling the `Container` which is active.

Comment: Ah I see now; it seems intuitive to me thatreact would find a way to transfer state access between components without getting property involved as an in between step but they're the experts