# Passing current element to onClick function - React Jsx

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a div, i want to pass `this` div to onlick function and change it's class (or add class).

```
<div className="history-node" onClick={() => this.handleHistoryClick(this)}>
     <span className="history-title">Uploaded</span>
     <span className="history-date">October 9, 2017</span>
</div>
```

Function is:

```
handleHistoryClick(el){
      console.log("History Clicked");
      console.log(el);
}
```

But this is printing current React Component Class which is
`Paymentdetail`.

What i want is:

```
handleHistoryClick(el){
     $(el).addClass('active');
}
```

**EDIT:**  I have multiple `history-node` elements. So adding state to change class won't work for multiple elements.

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react change class name on state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224113/react-change-class-name-on-state-change)

Comment: No it's not. Because i have multiple `history-node` elements. How to determine states for all of them? only one can have `active` state.

Comment: store an array of states then, not just one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` in your code refer to the component and not the element:

```
<div className="history-node" onClick={() => this.handleHistoryClick}>
     <span className="history-title">Uploaded</span>
     <span className="history-date">October 9, 2017</span>
</div>
```

component :

```
handleHistoryClick(event){
      let el = event.target;
      el.classList.add('active');
      // $(el).addClass('active'); I'm not familiar with jquery but try it
}
```

**edit** : As @sag1v said : it is better to bind the handler in the constructor (or use arrow function) instead of creating a new function instance on each render.
just like this :

```
constructor(){
   this.handleHistoryClick= this.handleHistoryClick.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: it is better to bind the handler in the constructor (or use arrow function) instead of creating a new function instance on each render

Comment: Typically you want React to handle modifying the DOM. this answer is somewhat fragile depending on how the rest of the code is written

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using  this.handleHistoryClick(this)}>

use this...

this.handleHistoryClick.bind(this)}>