# Change style in JSS

Tags: reactjs, jss

I have the following component using JSS:

```
import React from 'react'
import injectSheet from 'react-jss'

const styles = {
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
  }
}

class App extends Component {
    changeStyle = () => {
         styles.button.backgroundColor: 'blue' //this obviously doesn't work
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <button className={this.props.classes.button} onClick={this.changeStyle}>Switch user</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is definitely a simple question. When I click button I expect that background will change to 'blue', but just assigning new color doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react change class name on state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224113/react-change-class-name-on-state-change)

Answer (score 3):

## Conditional Styles in JSS

In JSS you should be using a function to inject style names (as strings) into the component. I assume you're using injectSheet to inject classes into the props, and just left that out of your code sample. injectSheet will inject the classes object that contains key value pairs like so: [styleObjectPropertyName]: [dynamicInjectedCSSPropertyName], and it will inject the CSS into the header of the page.

When you try to edit the style object after this happens, it is not reactive, so you need to prepare your CSS styles beforehand and remove or apply them dynamically in the code.

### classNames package

You can use a simple library like [classNames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) to conditionally apply styles, which is the way I've outlined below.

```
import React from 'react';
import injectSheet from 'react-jss';

const styles = {
  buttonPink: {
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
  },
  buttonBlue: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
};

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isButtonColorPink: true,
  };

  changeButtonColor = () => {

  }

  render() {
    const { buttonColorPink } = this.state;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button className={classNames({ 
          [classes.buttonPink]: isButtonColorPink,
          [classes.buttonBlue]: !isButtonColorPink,
        })} onClick={this.toggleStyle}>Switch user</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default injectSheet(styles)(App);
```

Alternatively you can just use inline styling for any dynamic styling - something like `style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.buttonColor }}` inside the button, and simply change buttonColor property with a thisState inside a class method.

Comment: It does not anwser the question. Is this somtehing that is not allowed in the JSS api?

Comment: Assuming he left out the part of the code what injects the styles object with injectSheet, when he is trying to change the style, injectSheet would have already injected styles into the page (by injecting a string class names to className inside this.props.classes, which refers to the style injected into the header). When you try to change the style object, it is not reactive. I believe this answers the question because it illustrates a correct way to do things, but I'll clarify my answer in a moment.

Comment: I added an answer using function values which let you change properties of a style

Answer (score 0):

With JSS version 7.1.7+, you can use function values to define your styles.

```
const styles = {
  button: {
    color: data => data.color
  }
}
```

when you need to change the color, call the `update` method of the `sheet` prop:

```
this.props.sheet.update({
  button: {
    color: 'red',
  }
})
```

Please note that as of August, 2018 there are [limitations](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/issues/682) to using function values

Answer (score -1):

The ideal pattern is to store the color of the button in a state object, then update that state when you want to change the color.

One solution to your problem is something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import injectSheet from 'react-jss'


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {buttonColor: 'pink'};

  }
    changeStyle = (color) => {
      this.setState({
        buttonColor: color
      });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <button className={this.props.classes.button} onClick={ this.changeStyle }>Switch user</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```