# Does e.target.classList.{add || remove || toggle } dangerouslySetInnerHtml?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, element, virtual-dom

Wanted to ask people with more experience with React about this, since I can't seem to find a definitive answer.  I know you don't want to add text to the DOM directly, which is why React makes you write `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` in order to set it.

But what about `classList.{ add || remove || toggle }`?  Is using `classList.add() || .remove()` tantamount to `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`?  Should I be worried about doing this, too?

Case in point - a function that renders a list from inside a component styled with bootstrap css.

Problem: Set add/remove `.active` to `li className` on mouse hover.

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const RenderList = (array, position = 'text-center') => {
    const handleMouseEnter = e => {
        e.target.classList.add('active');
    };

    const handleMouseLeave = e => {
        e.target.classList.remove('active');
    };

    return (
        <ul className={`list-group ${position}`}>
            {array.map(({ href, key, label, rel, target }) => (
        <a key={key} href={href} rel={rel} target={target} fontSize={1.2}>
          <li
            className={`list-group-item '${key}'`}
          
            data-id={key}
            onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
            onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
          >
            {label}
          </li>
        </a>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
};
export default RenderList;
```

The problem is - I've tried setting this in state, but it affects all `li`s at once (I've seen this issue in other questions - albeit, not for functional components, but for classes)

Is this safe?  I don't see any warnings in my browser.

If it's not safe, what's the alternative?  I tried using a `data-id` attribute from the key for the `li`, but I wasn't quite able to wrap my head around `useState` for a single element...

Edit:  A question was suggested as a possible answer, but it recommends making a separate instance of state for each list item, which doesn't seem like a very good solution.

Comment: Are you saying adding a class is unsafe??

Comment: No, it's not dangerous. Whether it's safe to swap out classes without React knowing about it, I can't tell.

Comment: Why add a class on mouse hover instead of using `:hover` in CSS?

Comment: It is definitely an anti-pattern in React to mess with the DOM by hand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react change class name on state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224113/react-change-class-name-on-state-change)

Comment: @epascarello I am *asking* if it's unsafe.  I can't really tell.

Comment: @bergi I can't tell either.

Comment: @Emile Bergeron Because the CSS isn't set up to work that way - I agree it's messy when working w/ virtDom. And lastly, yes that does answer the question, but also requires a state object for every single  LI, and is also a component, not a function.  It's untenable to make a state object for all the LIs, and cannot be done dynamically.

Comment: Anything done with a class component can be done with function components now. So that's a non-issue. You could make the item a small component that manages its own state and events.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218484/discussion-between-averyfreeman-and-emile-bergeron).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Mutating the DOM manually is an anti-pattern in React

React is a data-first UI lib, meaning that the data dictates how it should render, and it (almost) never need to read the DOM. It only writes to the DOM, and with its internal diffing algorithm, it computes the minimal chunks to update in the DOM.

When mutating the DOM ourselves, React won't be aware of our changes and might wipe our efforts in the next render phase.

## Toggling styling on mouse hover

Whenever possible, favor CSS selectors over JavaScript to style your components. In this case, it would be a simple selector:

```css
.list-group li:hover {
  /* `.active` styles here */
}
```

## How to toggle classes on each item?

To avoid managing the state of each individual items in the list component, I'd make an `Item` component which manages its own state and events, leaving the parent list to focus on its actual logic.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Manages its own state and events, making it 
// possible to toggle the class here instead.
const Item = ({ to }) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <li
      className={active? 'active' : ''} 
      onMouseEnter={() => setActive(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setActive(false)}
    >
      <a data-link={to}>{to}</a>
    </li>
  );
};

// No more class toggling logic needed here.
const List = ({ items }) => (
  <ul>
    {items.map((itemProps) => <Item {...itemProps} />)}
  </ul>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <List items={[{ to: '/home' }, { to: '/foo' }]} />,
  document.querySelector('[data-role-react-root]')
);
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-role-react-root></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a remarkably helpful answer, and I'm surprised how simple the solution is - to move the li and the useState instance outside of the ul.  I didn't think of that.  I'm definitely going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found a solution to this, but I'm not exactly sure if it's the correct way to do it.  It still manipulates the DOM, but using the state - so presumably React can decide when to do it:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const RenderList = (array, position = 'text-center') => {
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(null);
const [isNotActive, setIsNotActive] = useState(null);

const handleMouseEnter = e => {
  setIsActive(e.target.classList.add('active'));
};

const handleMouseLeave = e => {
  setIsNotActive(e.target.classList.remove('active'));
};

    return (
        <ul className={`list-group ${position}`}>
            {array.map(({ href, key, label, rel, target }) => (
        <a key={key} href={href} rel={rel} target={target} fontSize={1.2}>
          <li
            className={`list-group-item '${key}'`}
          
            data-id={key}
            onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
            onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
          >
            {label}
          </li>
        </a>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
};
export default RenderList;
```

Would love feedback