# Is there a way to change the className of an already existing react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component **(c1)** which renders another react component **(c2)** which renders another react component **(c3)**.

I want to change the **"className"of c3** when a user presses a radio button in **c1**.

I know one can use refs in react to access components, but a think it's too complicated for this problem because I would have to create the ref in c1 and pass it to c2 and then pass it to c3.
And I am not even sure that this would work.

Any help is appreciated.

NOTE: I do not really want to put all the code in the same .js file because it will result in a very large, unreadable, undebuggable code..

Comment: What do you want to change the class name? What do these components do? Maybe there is an other way to achieve your actual goal?

Comment: Usually you should show some code

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). If you need to change the className, it's likely because some state changed you're reacting to. Therefore, change the state in c1 and react to the state change in c3.

Comment: Doesn't seem so bad to pass down two levels... ReactContext maybe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react change class name on state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224113/react-change-class-name-on-state-change)

Comment: Thank you very much y'all finally archieved passing a list of attributes as props and if the component id was on the list attributes then I pass the a custom className to the component3. I am starting to understand React xD

Comment: what do you mean when saying : NOTE: Changing the components to be all in the same place it's the last option because it will be a really big spaguetti code.

I dont get it.

Comment: Putting all react code inside the same .js file then It would be more easy to solve the problem but I will have unredeable spaguetti code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without using refs.

```js
function Component1() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('disabled')
  
  function handleOnChange() {
    setName(previous => previous === 'disabled' ? 'enabled' : 'disabled')
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <label>Change class name</label>
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleOnChange} />
      <Component2 mainClass={name} />
    </div>
  )
}

function Component2({ mainClass }) {
  return <Component3 mainClass={mainClass} />
}

function Component3({ mainClass }) {
  return <div className={mainClass}>Hello World</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Component1 />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: #666;
}

.enabled {
  color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```