# How to make the label of a slider translate in the X axis to fit the width of the slider using CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, slider

I want the label of the slider to translate in the X axis to fit the current width of the slider as I demonstrate in the [gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/Ytttd7RjoRL9YLVPT2/giphy.gif). It is hard to explain what I want using words so please watch the gif to understand what I am trying to achieve.

I already have the slider made up using material ui and react but I am not able to achieve the effect I showed in the gif.

> Here's the css I have for the slider right now:

```
:root {
  --slider-width: 60%;
}

.slider-container {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;

  bottom: 50vh;
  width: var(--slider-width);
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 10px;
}

span [class^="PrivateValueLabel-circle"] {
  width: max-content !important;
  height: fit-content !important;
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-35%) translateY(5px) !important;
  border-radius: 0% 0% 0% 0% !important ;
}

span [class^="PrivateValueLabel-label"] {
  margin: 9px;
  transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
}
```

> Here is the code I used for the slider

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Slider from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import "./app.css";

const TextSlider = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(-1);
  const [marks, setMarks] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    if (newValue !== value) {
      setValue(newValue);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setMarks([
      "2020 trimestre 1",
      "2020 trimestre 2",
      "2020 trimestre 3",
      "2020 trimestre 4",
      "2021 trimestre 1"
    ]);
    setValue(0);
  }, []);

  if (value === -1) {
    return <div />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="slider-container">
      <Slider
        aria-label="asdsds"
        value={value}
        color="primary"
        getAriaValueText={(value, index) => {
          return marks[value];
        }}
        valueLabelFormat={(value, index) => {
          return marks[value];
        }}
        aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-custom"
        step={1}
        min={0}
        max={4}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
        onChange={handleChange}
        track={false}
        marks={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextSlider;
```

Here's a condesandbox with the current slider that doesn't have the functionality I want to achieve: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-fd3m5?file=/app.css

Comment: is this what you mean ?  https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-y7yjl You should add some of your code that can demonstrate your issue :(

Comment: Please if someone voted down my question tell my what is the reason so I can improve it.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus that is what I actually wanted to achieve. I thought it was clear with the gif I posted what I wanted. Futhermore, I added the codesandbox with the current code I have. If you want to post an answer with the codesandbox you made I will check it as correct answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess it is because your question is made of links and you provided no code here . not that easy with react, but you try to build a snippet from that one  which has the library needed to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63885115/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-classname-of-an-already-existing-react-component

Comment: But I think for this type of question is better to post de codesandbox right? So anybody who wants to answer the question has the code and can try to solve it there. I think it's more easy for the solver.

Comment: If you pst the code of the components and your CSS it helps a lot to see what your trouble is about , links can be dead really quick and then the Q/A becomes useless to anyone else with the same issue. `const TextSlider ...`+ the css would give a good view . Most of the time i do not follow links. I did , because i'm thinking of trying to do some react-native code to teach myself ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the style value of the parent and reset the translatex() value via CSS.

example via CSS only :

```
:root {
  --slider-width: 60%;
}

.slider-container {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;

  bottom: 50vh;
  width: var(--slider-width);
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 10px;
}

span [class^="PrivateValueLabel-circle"] {
  width: max-content !important;
  height: fit-content !important;
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-35%) translateY(5px);
  border-radius: 0% 0% 0% 0% !important ;
}

span [class^="PrivateValueLabel-label"] {
  margin: 9px;
  transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
}
.MuiSlider-thumb[style="left: 0%;"] span.MuiSlider-valueLabel {
  transform: translate(45%, -35%);
}
.MuiSlider-thumb[style="left: 25%;"] span.MuiSlider-valueLabel {
  transform: translate(20%, -35%);
}
.MuiSlider-thumb[style="left: 75%;"] span.MuiSlider-valueLabel {
  transform: translate(-20%, -35%);
}

.MuiSlider-thumb[style="left: 100%;"] span.MuiSlider-valueLabel {
  transform: translate(-45%, -35%);
}
.MuiSlider-thumb[style] span.MuiSlider-valueLabel {
  transition: 0s;
}
```

Best would be to do that from the script itself whie assigning the left position to the created elements.